# disable auto-save in editable datagrid Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, adobe, flex4

I have an editable datagrid, whenever I make a change it automatically gets saved. How can I disable this? So the changes gets saved only when I click on an external save button.

Comment: won't calling the event.preventDefault() on ITEM_EDIT_END will stop the dataprovider from getting updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel the itemEditEnd event by calling event.preventDefault() in the event listener

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event:itemEditEnd